# Label with tags highest values in a column

Tags: html, bash, awk, sed, tabular

Given the table below, I would like to sum up each row separately, find out which is the highest and second highest value of the summed up values and put a marker in the corresponding row (e.g a html tag, for the first summed value: `<b>num1</b>` and for the second highest value: `<i>num2</i>`):

```
cat input.txt
0.743745 0.00145661
0.740159 0.00208729
0.743907 0.0019944
0.769515 0.0051214
0.768735 0.00453603
0.755945 0.00203796
```

If we sum up each row of the input file, we'll obtain the following values:

```
0.7452
0.7422
0.7459
0.7746
0.7733
0.7580
```

Given these computed values, the desired output should look like:

```
cat output.txt
0.743745 0.00145661
0.740159 0.00208729
0.743907 0.0019944
<b>0.769515 0.0051214</b>
<i>0.768735 0.00453603</i>
0.755945 0.00203796
```

Comment: basically create a new array with the sums, use bc, awk or this link[1] for the float operations. While summing use 2 other vars to find the 2 biggest values. Then you know which lines in the original array are biggest. But don't expect others to write your homework.

[1] http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/floating-point-math-bash

Comment: +1 for good formatting, sample input, sample output, problem description, errr...sample code? oh well can't have everything. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

see below:

```
kent$  cat test
0.743745 0.00145661
0.740159 0.00208729
0.743907 0.0019944
0.769515 0.0051214
0.768735 0.00453603
0.755945 0.00203796

kent$  awk '{a[NR]=$0;s=$1+$2;
if(m==""||s>m){m=s;mr=NR; }
if(n==""||(s>n&&s<m)){n=s;nr=NR;} }
END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(i==mr) print "<b>"a[i]"</b>" 
        else if(i==nr) print "<i>"a[i]"</i>"
        else print a[i]}' test
0.743745 0.00145661
0.740159 0.00208729
0.743907 0.0019944
<b>0.769515 0.0051214</b>
<i>0.768735 0.00453603</i>
0.755945 0.00203796
```

Comment: @Kent, thanks for your script. I used another file, but it seems to be that the output isn't as expected. The test file that I used is: http://pastebin.com/DWar8k2Y Could you please have a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print NR"\t"$0"\t"$1+$2}' input.txt |
  sort -k3gr |
    sed -r -e '1s#\t(.*)\t#\t<b>\1</b>\t#' -e '2s#\t(.*)\t#\t<i>\1</i>\t#' |
      sort -n |
        cut -f2
```

---

```
0.743745 0.00145661
0.740159 0.00208729
0.743907 0.0019944
<b>0.769515 0.0051214</b>
<i>0.768735 0.00453603</i>
0.755945 0.00203796
```

Comment: +1 for stepped formatting and intriguing use of unix(linux) toolbox features to solve problem. Good luck to all.

Comment: @kev, thanks for the illustration. I tested your script with another input file, but I'm not sure if it works in all cases, e.g. with this file: http://pastebin.com/DWar8k2Y